# Generate XML from Hash with `.to_xml`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to generate some XML that is in the following format:

```xml
<Envelope>
    <Body>
        <importPurchaseOrder>
            <orderDetails>
                <headerdetails>
                    <id>123</id>
                    <repairer_id>456</repairer_id>
                    <linedetails>
                        <id>789</id>
                    </linedetails>
                    <linedetails>
                        <id>101</id>
                    </linedetails>
              </headerdetails>
           </orderDetails>
        </importPurchaseOrder>
    </Body>
</Envelope>
```

So I have been doing this first by creating a hash then using `.to_xml` to convert the hash to XML:

```rb
  def build_purchase_order_payload(purchase_order)
    {
      orderDetails: {
        headerdetails: {
          id: purchase_order.id,
          repairer_id: purchase_order.repairer&.rep_name,
          linedetails: build_purchase_order_items_line(purchase_order.purchase_order_items)
        }
      }
    }.to_xml(root: 'importPurchaseOrder')
  end


  def build_purchase_order_items_line(purchase_order_items)
    purchase_order_items_detail = []
    purchase_order_items.each do |purchase_order_item|
      purchase_order_item_detail = {}
      purchase_order_item_detail.merge!({
                                          id: purchase_order_item.id
                                        })
      purchase_order_items_detail.push(purchase_order_item_detail)
    end
    purchase_order_items_detail
  end
```

This generates XML in the following output:

```xml
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>
<importPurchaseOrder>
  <orderDetails>
    <headerdetails>
      <id type=\"integer\">102371</id>
      <repairer-id>12345</repairer-id>
      <linedetails type=\"array\">
        <linedetail>
          <id type=\"integer\">197885</id>
        </linedetail>
        <linedetail>
          <id type=\"integer\">197886</id>
        </linedetail>
      </linedetails>
    </headerdetails>
  </orderDetails>
</importPurchaseOrder>
```

The issue being the `<linedetails>` generating nested `<linedetail>`.

How can I match the generated XML to the required format? I do not wish to use a Gem.

Comment: You already have an XML parser gem installed, nokogiri.  That's your best bet for modifying the XML to meet your needs. https://nokogiri.org/tutorials/modifying_an_html_xml_document.html

Answer (score 0):

I would just embrace the fact the XML is a document format and use a templating engine instead of `#to_xml` which is woefully naive idea as it really only covers the most trivial of cases.

In fact Ruby has a built template engine in that can render any format - and you have already used it - [ERB](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.1/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html).

```
# import_purchase_orders/_envelope.xml.erb
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Envelope>
  <Body>
    <importPurchaseOrder>
      <orderDetails>
        <headerdetails>
          <id><%= order.id %></id>
          <repairer_id><%= order.repairer&.rep_name %></repairer_id>
          <% items.each do |item| %>
          <linedetails>
            <id><%= item.id %></id>
          </linedetails>
          <% end %>
        </headerdetails>
      </orderDetails>
    </importPurchaseOrder>
  </Body>
</Envelope>
```

In Rails 5+ its really trivial to get Rails to render a template at any point in your application like from a model or a service object:

```
ApplicationController.render(
  partial: 'import_purchase_orders/envelope',
  formats: :xml,
  locals: {
    order: purchase_order,
    items: purchase_order.purchase_order_items
  }
)
```